# flutter: Invalid key hash when using facebook login on playstore released version of the app (relese key hash is generated)

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, facebook-login

Whenever I try to login with Facebook through the app I get an invalid key hash the key hash xxxxxxxx doesn't match any stored key hashes.
I have already generated the release key hash and updated it in the Meta for Developers app and the app was working just fine but after uploading some updates to the play store I got this error.
when I try to add the key hash I get from the error displayed in the app I get the same error with the same key I just updated.

so right now the release key hash and the key hash from the error on the app are added to the key hashes on MetaforDevelopers and I still get the same error in the app.

Am I doing something wrong?
have anyone faced a similar problem?

**Update** : I discovered that this behaviour happens because of the Facebook app, when I disable the Facebook app I can login successfully.